# Customize Ment.io AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm using [jeff-collins](http://jeff-collins.github.io/ment.io/#/) angularjs directive in my project. I need some help customizing the directive. I want to be able to search with spaces. Be able to hit the space button without selecting the item.

So the problem I've is that my autocomplete list contains Firstname + Lastname. In jeff's example he only got Firstname. My list is like:

- Foo Bar
- Foo Ber
- Bar Foo

So the problem starts when I want to search for firstname and lastname. For example I search for: "foo b". When I hit the space button after "foo" it selects the item. I don't want that to happen becuse I still want to search.

I checked the code and I found this:

```
if (event.which === 13 || event.which === 32) {
event.preventDefault();
activeMenuScope.selectActive();
```

}

So I removed the part "event.which === 32". Now it dosen't select the item anymore so I'm almost there. But what's happening now when I press the space button is that it closes the autocomplete list.

Is there anyone who can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be dealing with an older version of ment.io.  The current version will handle this case without dismissing the menu.  This functionality was added some time ago.

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem. And thank you for sharing this directive with us.

Comment: Hi jeff! I just noticed that ment.io is leaking memory. First I thought it was my application but then I saw it was the same on your example page (http://jeff-collins.github.io/ment.io/#/examples) you had the same problem.

Comment: Hi jeff!! Is their any alternative for ment.io to be used in angular 5 project.. Stuck with it and tried with angular-mentions but having many limitations.